# crosscompile c++ binary for Amazon EC2

Tags: c++, amazon-ec2

I tried to just compile on what appears to be similar (both Ubuntu 64bit) but the binary is not runnable by the Amazon instance of Ubuntu (which is 64 bit too, but don't know much more than that).

I've seen a thread suggesting spinning additional EC2 instance just to compile there, but it isn't a solution as I can't transfer sources outside, only a compiled binaries and dynamic libs.

Was thinking about making a virtual environment on my computer to spawn a clone of EC2 to compile there, but is it doable?

kernel info:

```
uname -a
4.4.0-93-generic                 #116-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 21:17:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx 4.4.0-1035-aws #44-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 12 17:27:47 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

it uses some amazon tailor made kernel it seems?

file info:

```
file ./testBinary
./testBinary: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), too many program (2304)
file -Pelf_phnum=3000 ./testBinary 
./testBinary: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), corrupted program header size, corrupted section header size
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't really 'clone' EC2 instance that you've created from some AMI. So since you don't have any details about why exactly your library wasn't working, I would suggest running Amazon Linux instead of Ubuntu.

You can run Amazon Linux in a Docker container on your machine and build your library there (https://hub.docker.com/_/amazonlinux/). That way the library should run without problems in any EC2 with Amazon Linux.

If you want to stick with Ubuntu, at the very least you should match Ubuntu versions (not just architecture) and probably kernel versions.

Comment: Added kernel information, as for running error it's the standard 'cannot execute binary file: Exec format error' error you get when trying to run a binary of different type I think something like that happens when you try to run ARM binary on x86 for example.

Comment: That does seem like arm binary or something. But you can start debugging with simple `file /path/to/your/executable` on the target system to see what it looks like.

Comment: new info from file ./executable - I tried looking for this output but I found case where someone was trying to crack a program where file was protected from disassembly. This testBinary I compiled myself from sources and didn't do anything to it. Runs on physical computer with ubuntu if all dependencies are met.